# Inheritance from one instance in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I want to know if it's possible having something like this:

- basic class **A**
- derived class **B1** from one instance **a** of class **A** (i.e. `a = new A()` )
- derived class **B2** from same instance **a** of **A**

I give an example:

```
var a = new A();
function A() {
    this.var_test = 0;
    this.test = function () {
        alert(this.var_test++);
    }
}

function B1() {
}
B1.prototype = a;

function B2() {         
}
B2.prototype = a;

var b1 = new B1();
var b2 = new B2();
b1.test(); // i want alert(0)
b2.test(); // i want alert(1)
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

[Sure, just use the standard methods for inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain):

```js
console.clear();
function A() {
  this.test = function() {
    alert(A.var_test++);
  }
  A.var_test = 0;
}
var a = new A();
b1 = Object.create(a);
b2 = Object.create(a);
b1.test();
b2.test();
b1.test();
b2.test();
```

Comment: yeeeah, that's what i need! thank you for your example

Answer (score 0):

Here’s some recommended reading from Douglas Crockford on classical inheritance in JavaScript: http://javascript.crockford.com/inheritance.html

As he says, quite succinctly:

> JavaScript is a class-free, object-oriented language, and as such, it uses prototypal inheritance instead of classical inheritance. This can be puzzling to programmers trained in conventional object-oriented languages like C++ and Java. JavaScript's prototypal inheritance has more expressive power than classical inheritance […]